# How does paging page tables size of the outer page table?

Tags: memory, memory-management, paging

I understand paging the pages tables does reduces the size of the overall outer page table.

But is this solving the problem of reducing space of the pages stored as we also store the actual inner page tables in memory anyway.

So aren't was stored everything we used to store anyway in memory? So how is this reducing space.